# How to return an array of .NET objects via a COM method

Tags: .net, com, c++-cli, com-interop, safearray

I have a .NET assembly.  It happens to be written in C++/CLI.  I am exposing a few objects via COM.  Everything is working fine, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to return an array of my own objects from a method.  Every time I do, I get a type mismatch error at runtime.  I can return an array of ints or strings just fine.

Here is my main class

```
[Guid("7E7E69DD-blahblah")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType::None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public ref class Foo sealed : IFoo
{
public:
    virtual array<IBar^>^ GetStuff();
}

[Guid("21EC1AAA-blahblah")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType::InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]  
public interface class IFoo
{
public:
    virtual array<IBar^>^ GetStuff()
    {
        // For simplicity, return an empty array for now.
        return gcnew array<IBar^>(0);
    }
};
```

Here is the class I am returning

```
[Guid("43A37BD4-blahblah")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType::InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]  
public interface class IBar
{
    // Completely empty class, just for testing.  
    //In real life, I would like to return two strings and an int.
};

[Guid("634708AF-blahblah")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType::None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Serializable]
public ref class Bar : IBar
{
};
```

This is my (native) C++ code that calls it:

```
MyNamespace::IFooPtr session(__uuidof(MyNamespace::Foo));
// For simplicity, don't even check the return.
session->GetStuff();
```

Calling GetStuff() gets me a _com_error 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH).  I can tell my method is being called correctly, it's just that when .NET/COM goes to marshall the return, it chokes.  As I said, it works fine with arrays of ints or strings.  What do I have to do to my class to allow it to be returned in an array?

As it happens, my class will only contain a couple of strings and an int (no methods), if that makes it any easier.  Obviously I've tried returning a non-empty array and classes that actually contain some data, this is just the simplest case that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `IDispatch` and the `Enumerator` method

```
public ref class FooCollection{
[DispId(-4)]
public IEnumerator^ GetEnumerator()
{
//...
}
}
```

Comment: So I can't just return an array, I have to write my own collection class and expose that?  Disappointing, but I suppose not too difficult.

Comment: @mhenry1384, if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6340144/12048) is correct then it should be possible.