# return array from com object

Tags: c++, com, vbscript

I want to pass a list of alarm names from COM to VBScript used in ASP pages.  If the method name is `GetAlarms`, What would be the signature of the method?. The number of alarms returned by `GetAlarms` will vary.

Does VBScrip support Safe Array?

Comment: @Maanu: Why is this tagged C++? In C++ you cannot return arrays from a function.

Comment: @Als Unless he means a `SAFEARRAY`.

Comment: @Als: We are writing the COM component in C++

Comment: VBScript *requires* SAFEARRAY.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Can I get an example for this?

Comment: My Apologies, don't know much about `VBscript`,not my area of work or competency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration in the *.idl file would look like this:

```
[id(1)] HRESULT GetAlarms([out,retval] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)* pAlarms);
```

The corresponding C++ method would look like this:

```
STDMETHODIMP CMyClass::GetAlarms(SAFEARRAY** pAlarms)
{
    CComSafeArray<VARIANT> alarms(3);
    CComVariant value;

    value = L"First Alarm";
    alarms.SetAt(0, value);

    value = L"Second Alarm";
    alarms.SetAt(1, value);

    value = L"Third Alarm";
    alarms.SetAt(2, value);

    *pAlarms = alarms.Detach();

    return S_OK;
}
```

And finally, here is a sample VBScript that uses the above method:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("MyLib.MyClass")
a = obj.GetAlarms
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
   MsgBox a(i)
Next
```

In ASP, of course, you would use something else instead of `MsgBox`.